Can you just have one expensive coil on your front forks
would it be the same with a cheap one

Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. I do not really understand your question, coyld you specify it more? Also, do not just put everything into the title, tell us more in the question body. What kind of problem are you trying to solve (if any)? Why would you want an expensive coil?

I hate to challenge the premise of the question, but I don’t think you understand how suspension forks work.
With the exception of Cannondale’s Lefty line of forks, the spring is on one side of the fork and the other side contains the damper.
Typically, if upgrades are available for the fork, you upgrade the damper first. Air spring upgrades and air-to-coil conversion kits exist (but those are very niche).
If your fork isn’t air sprung, and the spring isn’t working well, you might need a different spring whose stiffness better matches your weight.
…Or your damper is fried
…Or your air spring is fried
…Or…
Without any information, it’s impossible to say what you should or even can do to improve your fork.
